# Scrolling android gridview blocking userinteraction

Tags: android, scroll, android-gridview

I have a gridview placed inside scrollview.

1. When app is launched the 12 items are displayed(page 1) in gridview.
2. WHen user scrolls and reaches the end of the scroll, next 12 items of next page is fetched via webservice, added to the initial array of items.
3. the notifydatasetchanged of gridview adapter is called and also the height of gridview is set dynamically.

But the issue is in point #3. This is blocking the user interaction for 1-2 seconds.

Please help.

Comment: it is not good practice to include listview,gridview inside scrollview.it wont work efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried performing the update in a thread?

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {     
//Update the grid view and set height.
```